# Evaluating Functions on Zero Sets (of other functions)

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions

I have a highly non-trivial function, call it $f(x,y)$, in which I want to look at its zero set in the $(x,y)$ plane, and plot/evaluate a different function $g$ precisely along this zero set.  I have a nice way of doing this when the zero set of $f$ can be parameterized by $x$, i.e. $y(x)$, but in general, this zero set will not be nicely parameterized by $x$.

Is there a nice way to parameterize zero sets by some parameter $t$, like length along the curve, and then save values and plot $g(x(t),y(t))$?  Perhaps it might be helpful to take an easy example like

`f[x_,y_]=x^2+y^2-4
g[x_,y_]=x^2-3*y^2`

Unlike the case of the circle above, my zero set certainly does not have a nice, obvious parameterization, so instead perhaps someone can help me form a numerical recipe using the simple example above.

**If it helps, I can upload the case I actually have in mind, but it's rather messy and requires a lot of pre-amble.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, MeshFunctions -> {f[#, #2] &},
  Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Thick, Red]}}}, BoxRatios->1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {f[#, #2] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Thick, Red]}}}, BoxRatios->1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},  ContourStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics3D[cp[[1]] /. GraphicsComplex[coords_, rest___] :> 
                        GraphicsComplex[{##, g[##]} & @@@ coords, rest], 
  BoxRatios -> 1,  Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  Perfect visualization of what I'm after.  The main thing I was after is a parameterization of the zero set such that I can save values of $g$ evaluated as a function of this parameter.  Is there a way to do this using the above, or is it simply a plotting technique?

Comment: @spietro, you can use the second example above as  `plot = Plot3D[...]`  to  extract the coordinates using `coords = Cases[Normal[plot], Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]]`.  In each triple in this list, the first two coordinates satisfy `f[x,y]==0` and the third coordinate is `g[x,y]`.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly and is precisely what I was hoping for; thanks!  Is there a way to vary the number of triples we output in `coords`?  Don't see a parameter that would control this.

Comment: @spietro,  you can play with `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` in `Plot3D` to change the number of points in `coords`-- but I don't know the exact mapping between the number of points in `coords`  the values of these two options.

Answer (score 3):

Can use `NDSolve` to parametrize numerically.

```
f[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 - 4;
g[x_, y_] = x^2 - 3*y^2;
pt = {2, 0};

xyvals = NDSolveValue[
  Flatten[{D[f[x[t], y[t]], t] == 0, x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 == 1, 
    Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == pt]}], {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 11}];
```

(If you want to see the better part of a circle, do `ParametricPlot[xyvals, {t, 0, 11}, AspectRatio -> 1]`)

Now to plot `g` on this set, do:

```
Plot[g @@ xyvals, {t, 0, 11}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  So it looks like `xyvals` is such that I can input some $t$ in the chosen range and output the corresponding $(x,y)$.  So it should be straightforward to choose discrete points in `xyvals` and save the associated $g(x(t),y(t))$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: So I've been playing with this code, and tried to apply it to cases where the zero set has more that one "component."  For example `f[x_, y_] = (x^2 + y^2 - 4) ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 4)`.  The resulting plot for `xyvals` picks up half of one circle, and half of the other.  Perhaps if the zero set has multiple disjoint components, you can parameterize just one component by choosing the initial point properly?  Can't seem to get that to work nicely.

Comment: (1) I'm really surprised that `NDSolve` jumped paths at a nontangential intersection. Anyway, as you note, multiple components and self intersections are both troublesome for the method, and so I should have stated it is really only local in nature. I do not know of a global approach. Best I can suggest is what you already know: use multiple initial points...

Comment: (2) So how to find a "full" set of initial points? Look for (1) extrema and (2) self-intersections. Both can be found via `NSolve` e.g. use Lagrange multipliers for the first and solve for `{f==0,D[f,x]==0,D[f,y]==0}` for the second.

Comment: (3) There might be something of use in [this recent Wolfram Technology Conference presentation](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9262/). And the author is working on expanding all this into an e-book.